# WAMP, Apache, IIS, MySql - differences and combinations

Tags: php, apache, iis, wamp

I'm so confused, I hope you can help me...
I know how to write php but never tried to build a local dev env.
For example - now, when I want to create a local WordPress site (to edit its php) - I see that I need to install WAMP, but that I also need IIS, and i'm so confused to understand who's doing what.
I already have php and Apache installed, so why do I need WAMP?
can someone give a good explanation about it (like the roles of each, why and when I need any of them, their combinations etc..), so afterward i'll know what to google and what to install?

Thank you!

Comment: If you use wamp you don't need iis and mysql since wamp is a windows package with all that.  execpt that wamp istead of using iis it use apache

Comment: But what are they actually?
Can you detail that and why/when do I need each?

Comment: Apache and IIS are both webServers  with diferent kind of settings since there are diferent solfware, Prety mutch the same as photoshop and paint are they are both for the same thing execpt one have some other function.   you may want to install all of them invidualy to have specifiq version of php or mysql for instance.

Comment: My recommendation is to uninstall your PHP and MySQL instance and just use WAMP which packages everything you need into one application and installation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WAMP` is the integration of Apache, MySQL and PHP.
If you will install `WAMP` in your local machine, then you don't need to install any other plugins/software/application to run your PHP script.

Furthermore, You don't need IIS at all to run PHP application.

Install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and turn on your server. You are ready to go.

**EDIT**

1) Apache: This is the web server. To run backend languages like C, Java, PHP, you need a server. People are using Apache by default in PHP application. You can also use `EngineX` or `IIS`.

2) MySQL: This is the database server. You can also use other databases in your PHP application.

**Conclusion**

All in all, you can use different technologies and integrate it if you want it like that. But, `WAMP` provides you basic structure, by means of that you don't need to setup these things by yourself.

Comment: But can you please explain what are all those and the differences?.. they're just words to me now, I really want to understand :\

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)
So is Apache like IIS?

Comment: http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-iis-and-apache/

Comment: Thank you!! :)
Can you please add a few words about tomcat as well and its position between all these?

Answer (score 1):

Apache is the web server. you need it to server your web site.

MySQL is the database server. You need it for the tables and data that will be used with WordPress.

WAMP installs a Windows version of Apache (with PHP enabled) and MySQL on your local machine so that you can run a local web server for development and testing.